# realm and IntentService

Tags: android, realm, intentservice

I have filled realm database. Everything works well.

The application has a button, pressing it starts IntentService. It is very simple for test

code here

```
public class HNotificationService extends IntentService {
    public HNotificationService() {
        super("HNotificationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("HNotificationService", "onHandleIntent");

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<HPartner> mResPartner = realm.where(HPartner.class).findAll();
        final HPartner hPartner = mResPartner.get(0);
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                hPartner.setName("test");
            }
        });
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

After this code is executed, the database becomes empty! I do not see any errors in the log.

Note. Cleaning the database occurs only when I want to record something.
I will be glad of any help

**EDIT1**

Inside application class. I use this code

```
  RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
  Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

**EDIT2**

yes you are right database is not deleted!

`Log.e("HNotificationService", "empty");` - It is never called, and it's good

```
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<HPartner> mResPartner = realm.where(HPartner.class).findAll();
        if (mResPartner.size() > 0) {
            Log.e("HNotificationService", "don't empty!");
        }

        final HPartner hPartner = mResPartner.get(0);
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                hPartner.setName("test");
            }
        });

        mResPartner = realm.where(HPartner.class).findAll();
        if (mResPartner.size() == 0) {
            Log.e("HNotificationService", "empty");
        }

        realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
        realm.close();
```

Another reason. When I go to a different screen I'm calling code

```
        mResPartners = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(HPartner.class).findAllAsync();
        mResPartners.removeChangeListeners();
        mResPartners.addChangeListener(mPartnersListener);
```

And mPartnersListener is never called. It is very strange.
if don't run IntentService. mPartnersListener always called

**EDIT 3**

```
 mPartnersListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<HPartner>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<HPartner> realmResult) {
                mResPartners.removeChangeListeners();
                mClusterManager.clearItems();
                mGoogleMap.clear();
                if (realmResult != null && realmResult.size() > 0) {
                    mListPartners = realmResult;
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LMarkerIcons.ID_LOADER, null, FrAroundMeMap.this);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: This looks normal. What is your realm configuration?

Comment: How do you detect the Realm is empty after executing that code?

Comment: Are U sure that U first add HPartner to DB ? realm.executeTransaction keep mechanism to catch Exeption if that occured and cancel transaction. 
To find out problem, U could use loggin. Check size of HPartner table and so on, log every step.
And how U know that your DB becomes empty ?

Comment: @Christian Melchior
please see edit2

Comment: @Vladymyr R.tmnko please see edit2

Comment: @Эвансгелист Evansgelist I want know version of realm, and code in mPartnersListener)) also U do async query here mResPartners = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(HPartner.class).findAllAsync() and it might be, that U add change listener to query, that not completed yet here mResPartners.addChangeListener(mPartnersListener);. Please, try to replace findAllAsync() to findAll() and check out what is going on =))

Comment: @Vladymyr R.tmnko Yes, I know that this is a  async query. And everything works fine!!! But after call IntentService, mPartnersListener don't never call again ((( I use classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.90.0"

Comment: @Vladymyr R.tmnko "findAll" - work, but that's not what I want

Comment: @ЭвансгелистEvansgelist please, check out my answer and tell, is this was helpful ? 
also, you use TOO MUCH **removeChangeListeners()** stuff, it might be difficult to find bug here. Maybe U should rethink using changeListeners approach ???

Comment: @Vladymyr R.tmnko ok, now I make a few tests. thanks for help!

Comment: Note that IntentService even though it is a LooperThread doesn't support ChangeListeners, since each `onHandleIntent` method call is considered a single event. There is no room where you can wait for the callback to be triggered. We should be more explicit about that in our documentation.

Comment: I did not catch the changes inside IntentService. After call IntentService ChangeListener do not work inside Fragments everywhere!

Comment: this code dont work inside fragment  mResPartners = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(HPartner.class).findAllAsync();
        mResPartners.removeChangeListeners();
        mResPartners.addChangeListener(mPartnersListener);

Comment: after use AsyncTaskLoader. ChangeListener works good! Problem only with IntentService

Answer (score 0):

I think, I find out the problem !You remove allChangelisteners in your IntentService, after logs in this part.

```
mResPartner = realm.where(HPartner.class).findAll();
    if (mResPartner.size() == 0) {
        Log.e("HNotificationService", "empty");
    }

    realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
    realm.close();
```

and then you do new query, add *NEW* changeListener and want get notifications from him, but after send notification, listener removed by code above.

adding changelistener to async fetched realmResult - correct, should work fine!
So remove this block in IntentSevice

```
realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
```

Also your listener looks very strange, see coments in your *onChange*

```
mPartnersListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<HPartner>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<HPartner> realmResult) {

            // here U remove listener BEFORE do your stuff and 
            // onChange will never called again 
            // If U`ll put log here U find out, that listener was called
            // simple delete block -> mResPartners.removeChangeListeners(); 

            mResPartners.removeChangeListeners(); 
            mClusterManager.clearItems();
            mGoogleMap.clear();
            if (realmResult != null && realmResult.size() > 0) {
                mListPartners = realmResult;
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LMarkerIcons.ID_LOADER, null, FrAroundMeMap.this);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I fond problem. If I use Service - ChangeListener work good. if I use IntentService - ChangeListener broken !!! IntentService - It has a separate thread. I think this is the cause of problems

Comment: Service runs on the same thread as it is started on (the UI thread). The IntentService runs on a second looper thread. I wonder if the looper can somehow "steal" the REALM_CHANGED message from the UI thread. @ChristianMelchior ?

Comment: No, we have an internal list of Realm on all Looper threads and each looper gets its own message.

Answer (score 0):

Something that bugs me in this code is that you should obtain the latest version of the realm object inside the transaction

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("HNotificationService", "onHandleIntent");

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<HPartner> mResPartner = realm.where(HPartner.class).findAll();
            final HPartner hPartner = mResPartner.get(0);
            hPartner.setName("test");
        }
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

Other than that, I would try replacing the `async()` query with the sync version.

```
mResPartners = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(HPartner.class).findAll();
```

Also worth noting the fact that `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(` this construct means you'll never be able to close the Realm on the UI thread.

EDIT: Are you sure

```
            mResPartners.removeChangeListeners();
```

Doesn't cause any problems in your change listener?

Comment: You don`t have to obtain the latest version of the realm object inside the transaction ! Transaction must contain code, which somehow modifies DB data, and be commited as quick, as possible !

Comment: findAllAsync - I call much later. Here the problem with the ChangeListener They don't call after IntentService. It is very strange!!!

Comment: Did you try what I said though.

Comment: i fond problem. If I use Service - ChangeListener work good. if I use IntentService - ChangeListener broken !!! IntentService - It has a separate thread. I think this is the cause of problems

Comment: Being on a separate thread shouldn't be a problem, but I do wonder if the Looper and Handler associated with the IntentService's own thread is a problem.

Comment: Apparently your problem is that `IntentService` is a looper thread, look: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2875

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I unfortunately did not solve the problem. But I knew if I use "beginTransaction/commitTransaction" code (in Sevice or IntentService), inside all my app stop work findAllAsync. If I use only "where" code (in Sevice or IntentService), all work perfect .
As result I can't update object inside Sevice/IntentService, because after the upgrade does not work findAllAsync inside ALL my app. it's horrible